# Handle exceptions in events

Tags: c#, events, exception

In this example I have two subscribers to my event. One of the subscribers raises an Exception but I would like to prevent all subscribers to fail when only one of them incurs in an Exception. The try-catch statement is not enough to capture the exception of the Dog class, it makes the Cat class fails too.

```
using System;

namespace EventsExample
{
    class BreadWinnerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class BreadWinner // publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler<BreadWinnerEventArgs> ArrivedHome; // 2.

        public void Action(BreadWinnerEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Papa says: I'm at home!");
            OnArriveHome(args);
        }

        protected virtual void OnArriveHome(BreadWinnerEventArgs args)
        {
            if (ArrivedHome != null)
            {
                foreach (EventHandler<BreadWinnerEventArgs> handler in ArrivedHome.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    try
                    {
                       var t = ArrivedHome; // publisher uses sames signature as the delegate
                       if (t != null)
                           t(this, args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error in the handler {0}: {1}", handler.Method.Name, e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Dog
    {
        public void OnArrivedHome(object source, BreadWinnerEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dog says: Whoof {0}!", e.Name)); 
        }
    }
    class Cat
    {
        public void OnArrivedHome(object source, BreadWinnerEventArgs e)
        { Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Cat hides from {0}", e.Name)); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BreadWinner papa = new BreadWinner(); // publisher
            Dog dog = new Dog(); // subscriber
            Cat cat = new Cat();
            papa.ArrivedHome += dog.OnArrivedHome; // subscription
            papa.ArrivedHome += cat.OnArrivedHome;

            papa.Action(new BreadWinnerEventArgs() { Name = "Papa" });
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, if an event handler raises an exception then the show is over.  You have absolutely no idea how to handle the exception yourself, you don't know anything about the code that failed.  And can therefore never restore state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it, you just where using `t` where you should have been using `handler`, you also where using `ArrivedHome` where you should have been using `t`. I also modified the code to wrap up all the exceptions and the delegate who called them in to a custom exception then wrap those in an aggragate exception and have the code raise that.

```
protected virtual void OnArriveHome(BreadWinnerEventArgs args)
{  
    var t = ArrivedHome; // publisher uses sames signature as the delegate
    if (t != null)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (EventHandler<BreadWinnerEventArgs> handler in t.GetInvocationList())
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    handler(this, args);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error in the handler {0}: {1}", handler.Method.Name, e.Message);

                    throw new DelegateException(handler, e, this, args); //Throw the exception to capture the stack trace.
                }
            }
            catch (DelegateException e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }
        if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}

///Elsewhere
sealed class DelegateException : Exception
{
    public Delegate Handler { get; }
    public object[] Args { get; }

    public DelegateException(Delegate handler, Exception innerException, params object[] args) : base("A delegate raised an error when called.", innerException)
    {
        Handler = handler;
        Args = args;
    }
}
```

However I don't think you really should be doing this, this deviates from the "expected behavior" and may catch other programmers off guard if they have to consume your classes that do this.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I wrote, just a little faster with the keyboard, +

Comment: Good answer, but I don't understand what is the "expected behavior". For me this is a good option to prevent subscribers to "break" the flow to other subscribers to the event.

Comment: "Normal" events break the flow when a exception is thrown. This is what people expect to happen, that is why your code does not do the "expected behavior".

Comment: @Rober did one more tweak to the code so the exception would hold a copy of the augments passed in to the delegate.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I see the new prop, that looks good in order to find out what went wrong, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying that you *should* do this, but this is one way to handle it:

```
protected virtual void OnArriveHome(BreadWinnerEventArgs args)
{
    var handler = ArrivedHome;

    if (handler == null)
        return;

    foreach (var subscriber in handler.GetInvocationList())
    {
        try
        {
            subscriber(this, args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //You can, and probably should, remove the handler from the list here
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to invoke each one of the subscribers individually instead of as a group, and catch an exception when one of them throws. The problem I have with doing this is that you really can't know what broke, or do anything to fix it. All you can do is log and optionally remove that event handler so that the next time you don't throw on that one.

Removing the handler may also be bad practice since it can be difficult to trace why a previously assigned handler is now unassigned.